# Program freeze when using KeyPressValidate event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code that I am using to prevent a user from entering alphabet characters on numeric only textfields.

```
empIDTextBox.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(KeyPressValidate);
empIDTextBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(KeyPressValidate); 

private void KeyPressValidate(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
            try
            {
                if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

The problem that I have is that when I am running the program to test it and I click into the `empIDTextBox` to enter a value for the first time, the validation works. When I click away from this textbox to another and then click back to the `empIDTextBox` to edit the entered value, I am unable to click anywhere else on the form, It like the whole program freezes and the cursor is stuck inside the `empIDTextBox` space.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I just checked your code in sample program... it works fine.... even when swtich to different controls and come back... no issue.. do you handle any other event of the textbox

Comment: For that specific textbox, there is no other event I am handling. I however use the same KeyPressValidate method to handle other textboxes on the form.

Comment: One more thing, the textbox is bound to a datasource. That might be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to enter only numeric value then i suggest you to use **NumericUpDown** control.

If you can't able to use that control due to whatever reason then what i have done is made seperate event for your textbox and use your code in my system and everything works fine.

```
private void empIDTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am still experiencing a problem. If you have a datasource and drag a textbox onto the form for a field and then add other databound textboxes, you might see the problem I am facing.